# Formulating spline interpolation as a matrix problem

Tags: multiple-regression, matrix, fitting, splines, interpolation

I have $N\times m$ data sets, with the same independent variables (time), i.e., $(t_i, y_{nmi})$.  I want to interpolate *(linear is fine, but understanding the generalizing for any set of basis functions would be awesome)* them all onto a different grid (lets say $t'_i$).  For speed/memory-efficiency I don't want to iterate over each $n,m$ an interpolate each one (especially since I'm using `python/numpy`), so I'm trying to formulate the problem using matrices which can then be computed more easily.

**I understand *(the basics of)* how to fit a set of basis functions as a matrix problem.**

Lets say we're fitting with a linear and sinusoidal model, so we have basis functions $[1, t, \sin(t), \cos(t)]$, so we can write,

$$
X(t) = 
\begin{bmatrix}
    1 & t_0 & \sin(t_0) & \cos(t_0) \\
    \dots \\
    1 & t_i & \sin(t_i) & \cos(t_i) \\
\end{bmatrix}
$$

with parameters, $B = [\beta_0, \beta_1, \beta_2, \beta_3]$, and then solve $Y = X(t) \, B$, (where $Y = y_{nm0}, y_{nm1}, ...$) to find the coefficients $B$...

$$B = (X^T X)^{-1} (X^T Y)$$

We can then interpolate using this fit to find $Y(t') = X(t') \, B$.

**But how do you extend this to be piecewise defined?**

There are lots of great wikipedia articles giving *procedures* of how to construct a spline (e.g. [1](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Monotone_cubic_interpolation), [2](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spline_interpolation), etc), but I haven't found any in which the extrapolation to a fully matricized implementation is clear...

For example, [this source](https://www.math.uh.edu/~jingqiu/math4364/spline.pdf) shows that you can write a linear spline as $S(x) = \sum_i^n y_i \, l_i(x)$, where,

$$
l_i(x) =
\begin{cases}
      \frac{x - x_{i-1}}{x_i - x_{i-1}}, & x \in [x_{i-1}, x_i] \\
      \frac{x_{i+1} - x}{x_{i+1} - x_{i}}, & x \in [x_{i}, x_{i+1}] \\
      0
\end{cases}
$$

But how can this be written as something like $X \, B$ above?

Comment: @Glen_b, you were very helpful in understanding general fitting formalisms, perhaps you have a pointer here as well?

Comment: the piece-wise part comes from the structure of matrices: they end up being sparse band matrices

Comment: @Aksakal right, depending on the order of the fit/spline, we want to grab something like $y_{i-1}, y_i, y_{i+1}$ to construct the fit for section $i$, i.e $S_i(x)$... but I'm not sure how this fits together.

Comment: what's not clear? there are so many little things that may be confusing, you better pinpoint the one you're struggling with. a general idea's the band matrix causes two things: a) each piece is a low order polynomial, and b) these are interlocked at each's ends. so, a) you need a few points to define low order polynomial thus the width of the bands in the matrix, and b) to make the spline smooth you need continuity of its derivatives, hence, overlapping the splines at the ends to ensure that

Comment: @Aksakal well, what exactly is the equation where this banded-diagonal matrix belongs?  In the equation I included above for $l_i(x)$, this clearly involves something like a banded diagonal matrix, but I don't know how to formulate it into an equation.  In other words, what equation to I solve to find the coefficients (piecewise defined), and then how do I plug back into them?

Comment: Are you confused about how did they come up with $l_i$ or with how to use this $l_i$?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/66229/discussion-between-dilithiummatrix-and-aksakal).

Comment: [possibly related/duplicate](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/284369/what-are-the-representations-of-splines-is-there-a-concept-of-a-0-degree-spline).